# php codeigniter - automatically send to users without clicking any button after x times

Tags: php, codeigniter

php codeigniter - im making a project that will send SMS message to users if they didn't see my post 3 minutes after posting it.

my question is how to call/execute a php function after 3 minutes without clicking any button and even if im logged out it will still run and send SMS.

Here's my function that will trigger my other function if they didn't see my post after 3 mins.

```
public function SendSMS(){

$getActivity = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_ssc_activity");
    while($activity=mysql_fetch_array($getActivity)){



$time_ago = strtotime($activity['posted_on']);

$cur_time   = time();
$time_elapsed   = $cur_time - $time_ago;
$seconds    = $time_elapsed ;
$minutes    = round($time_elapsed / 60 );
$hours      = round($time_elapsed / 3600);
$days       = round($time_elapsed / 86400 );
$weeks      = round($time_elapsed / 604800);
$months     = round($time_elapsed / 2600640 );
$years      = round($time_elapsed / 31207680 );
// Seconds
if($seconds>=60){
    if($minutes>=3){

        $this->SendSMStoUnseen();
```

and my function that will send SMS.

```
public function SendSMStoUnseen(){

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT
                         tbl_ssc_activity.mother_department AS mdept,
                         tbl_ssc_activity.activity_title AS title,
                         tbl_ssc_activity.activity_content AS content,
                         tbl_students.student_fname AS fname,
                         tbl_students.student_lname AS lname,
                         tbl_students.contact as cnt FROM tbl_ssc_activity INNER JOIN tbl_students ON
                         tbl_ssc_activity.mother_department=tbl_students.student_dept  
                         WHERE NOT EXISTS
                         (SELECT * FROM tbl_notifications WHERE tbl_notifications.seen_by=tbl_students.student_id AND
                            tbl_notifications.activity_id=tbl_ssc_activity.activity_id)");

     while($s=mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
         $mdept = $s['mdept'];
         $title = $s['title'];
         $content =  $s['content'];
         $student_fullname = $s['fname']." ".$s['lname'];
         $contact = $s['cnt'];


  $sendTo = $contact;
  $message = "To ". $contact . ": Hey " . $student_fullname . ", ".    $title ." - ". $content . " ". date('h:i.s');
  $API_CODE = "09356558078X85XEBQD";


$result = $this->itexmo($sendTo, $message, $API_CODE);
if ($result == ""){
echo "<H1>iTexMo: No response from server!!!</H1><br>"; 
}else if ($result){
echo "<H1> Message Sent! </H1> ".$message;
//header('Refresh: 5; URL=http://localhost/simpleSMS/');
}
else{   
echo "Error Num ". $result . " was encountered!";
}

}




}
```

Comment: please include code as text (using appropriate tags) instead of screenshots

Comment: @mfro sorry sir im new a stack overflow my bad :)

Answer (score 2):

you will need to create a cron job for this. This cron job will check for new post every 3 minutes, if any new post is there and the seen flag is flase then you can call the sms sending function.

Comment: thanks for the response sir but what is corn job? how to do this? im new in programming sir and im willing to learn

Comment: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/managing-cron-jobs-with-php--net-19428

It explains everything:

1.What is the format of the cronjob if you want to enter/edit it manually.
2.How to use PHP with SSH2 library to authenticate as the user, which crontab you are going to edit.
3.Full PHP class with all necessary methods for authentication, editing and deleting crontab entries.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use a queue system (such as redis) where you can add a task which will be performed 3 minutes after you posted it.

You can use Codeigniter-jobQueue from https://github.com/marsanla/Codeigniter-jobQueue.
Please check that page. Documentation is also provided.

After you installed and configured it into your CI installation, you can use it like:

```
$this -> jobs -> create_at( (time()+3*60) , 'high', 'myController', 'SendSMStoUnseen', $postId, 'check to send sms message','1');
```

The function SendSMStoUnseen() should have a postId as attribute and it should only check the post, and will only send messages for that specific post.

Btw: I think you want to change the SendSMS function from public to private

Comment: Difference between this solution and cron: You will run a cronjob every minute or 3 minutes for forever, while the queue solution will only run 3 minutes after you posted something. This wastes a lot less resources, and is also better fitted as a solution then the cron idea